# Set Visibility based on multiple properties

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a Canvas that I want to hide or show based off of 2 dependency properties:

```
IsPropA
IsPropB
```

If either of these are true I want the Canvas to display.  If both are false I want the Canvas to be hidden.

I know how I can do it with just 1 property.  But I'm unsure of how to do it with multiple properties.

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="2" x:Name="sesimicTeam" Visibility="{Binding IsPropA}">
```

Comment: Workaround: create a third property and put your logic for showing canvas there.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you could use [MultiDataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger.aspx)

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="2" x:Name="sesimicTeam">
    <Canvas.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsPropA}" Value="false" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsPropB}" Value="false" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Style>
</Canvas>
```

now it will show your Canvas if one of your Properties is true

Comment: anyone else wonder why we can't just state:  Visibility="{Binding IsPropA && IsPropB}" instead of creating a MultiDataTrigger?   WPF is very, crazy verbose!

Answer (score 28):

You can do this with a `IMultiValueConverter`.  That interface accepts any number of bindings and returns a single value.

**XAML**

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <converter:BooleanToVisibilityMultiConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityMultiConverter" />
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Canvas.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityMultiConverter}">
            <Binding Path="IsPropA" />
            <Binding Path="IsPropB" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Canvas.Visibility>
</Canvas>
```

**C#**

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.OfType<bool>().Any(b => b) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve this using a style with two triggers:

```
 <Canvas Grid.Row="2" x:Name="sesimicTeam">
        <Canvas.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Canvas">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPropA}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPropB}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Canvas.Style>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: yup that is the asnwer.

Comment: button lost Material Design color in this case. Used MultiBinding